# Django Import Error: cannot import name "Shift"

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty sure it's due to a circular import but I'm not too sure how to solve my issue

in ***mysite/shifts/models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class Shift(models.Model):
     # defines a shift`
```

in ***mysite/shifts/scrapes.py***

```
from shifts.models import Shift
```

I can share more code if you need but I believe the issue is here, I've added my apps to `settings.py` and I get this error when I run `scrapes.py` as a **django-admin** command

```
from shifts.models import Shift
ImportError: No module named 'shifts'
```

[project_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xg7P.png)

Comment: it looks like the Python path has been set wrong. You probably have set one above `mysite`.

Comment: What do you mean set one above?

Comment: Would you show your _folder_ structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line in **mysite/shifts/scrapes.py**

```
from .models import Shift
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from mysite.shifts.models import Shift
```

Comment: This solved that error! I now have an error: `from mysite.shifts.models import Shift
ImportError: No module named 'mysite'` I've tried including mysite in installed apps but no luck resolving it.

Comment: Okay, use from .models import Shift. The dot is the aktuall app

Comment: Now I've got `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` when will this end lol

Comment: Do you vorgot the dot ? .models import Shift, not from models import Shift.

Comment: . is in there `from .models import Shift`

Comment: I think it might be due to me trying to run scrapes.py as a django-admin command

Comment: Can you post the struktur of you project?

Comment: Just did :p when I've said "mysite" previously I was referring to "etip"

Comment: export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=etip.settings

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=.

Comment: `bash: export: `–': not a valid identifier`

Comment: No, use this in you console